# Different links from same array?

Tags: php, html, mysql, arrays

A kind user on here gave me this code:

```
$singles = valley_images();
$groups = valley_group_images();
$images = array_merge($singles, $groups);

$sortArray = array(); 

foreach($images as $image){ 
    foreach($image as $key=>$value){ 
        if(!isset($sortArray[$key])){ 
            $sortArray[$key] = array(); 
        } 
        $sortArray[$key][] = $value; 
    } 
} 

$orderby = "timestamp"; //change this to whatever key you want from the array 

array_multisort($sortArray[$orderby],SORT_DESC,$images); 

foreach($singles as $single) {
    echo '<img src="1/'.$image['album_id'].'/'.$image['code'].'.'.$image['ext'].'"/>';
}

foreach($groups as $group) {
    echo '<img src="groups/'.$image['group_id'].'/'.$image['code'].'.'.$image['ext'].'"/>';
}
```

Now what the problem is, i will be grabbing images from 2 different tables, images and group_images. But images are stored in the "1" folder while the group_images are stored in the "groups" folder. How would I manage to change the link depending on the table with that code, since the code doesn't tell the table it comes from?

The last 2 foreach statements are seperate and are not sorted. I am unsure on how to merge the foreach like that and get sorted.

Comment: One user gave you some code, another adapted it. What's your role? Management?

Comment: you have 2 options:  the best, edit the source of $images, to include the table. The terrible alternative -check each image against each folder in the loop to determine the correct link.

Comment: I edited the source of $images to include the 2nd table, but it problem is that it filters ALL of the images so sort them. I have updated the main post.

Comment: Why would the source code never know which table they came from? From this example it seems like that's abstracted out but you could change the code to somehow pass that information along.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

assuming this is the source of the data:

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT images.*, group_images.* ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");
```

i would change it to

```
$stmt = $conn->prepare("(SELECT images.*, 'single' as db from images) UNION  (SELECT group_images.*, 'group' as db from group_images) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC");
```

all else going well  you should have the array key of 'db' to use in the output to determine the link.

Comment: Alright I'll try that, thanks! I also just noticed that I never included the SQL query.